# How to read resource file in Play Framework >2.6?

Tags: playframework-2.6

All the answers to this problem relate to pre-2.6 play framework. Now, it seems that I need to inject an Environment into my Application, but even then, I get nothing.

I want to read in files from conf/i18n in my application root directory. I'm doing the following:

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration, assets: AssetsFinder, env: play.api.Environment) extends InjectedController {
    var root = System.getProperty("user.dir")
    var folder = new File(root + "/conf/i18n");
    var listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    val i18n = for {
      file <- listOfFiles
      filename = file.getName if filename.endsWith(".json")
      content = env.resourceAsStream("/conf/i18n/" + filename) match {
          case Some(stream) => Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines.mkString
          case None => ""
      }
   } yield Map(filename.dropRight(".json".length) -> Json.parse(content))

}
```

but the result of resourceAsStream is always None.

It works if I do it this way:

```
val i18n = for {
    file <- listOfFiles
    filename = file.getName if filename.endsWith(".json")
    content = Source.fromFile(folder + "/" + filename)("UTF-8").getLines.mkString
} yield Map(filename.dropRight(".json".length) -> Json.parse(content))
```

Any ideas?